# Average of key values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this list of dictionaries :

```
[{'Eva': [4, 8, 2]}, {'Ana': [57, 45, 57]}, {'Ada': [12]}]
```

I need to get the average of each key value, so that the output is :

```
[{'Eva': [5], {'Ana' : [53]}, {'Ada':[12]}]
```

The average must be rounded up or down by adding 0.5 and taking the only the integer part. For example, if the average is 4.3 adding 0.5 equals 4.8, so the output is 4. If the average is 4.6 adding 0.5 equals 5.1, so the output is 5.

I know how to use `iteritems()` to iterate over a dictionary, but since this is a list I don't know how to reach every value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Why do you have a list of dicts with a single key each, instead of just one dict?

Comment: I tried  with a for loop but it only gives me 'Eva' dictionary

Comment: You don't necessarily need to iterate over the list explicitly. You just use `sum` and then divide by the list length.

Comment: I will have to turn the final list of dictionaries into a .csv file being the first column the names of the owners and the second column their pets average age that's why I have several dicts in a list

Comment: @Stagg: That argues for what your output should be, not your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `numpy` functions `mean` and `round` for this task:

```
In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]:  [dict(zip(d.keys(), [int(np.round(np.mean(d.values())))])) for d in L]

#Out[9]: [{'Eva': 5}, {'Ana': 53}, {'Ada': 12}]
```

Version with "less" parenthesis:

```
[dict(zip(d.keys(), [np.array(d.values()).mean().round().astype(int)])) for d in L]
```

Comment: The expected output is dicts.

Comment: A list of dicts! And the average should be an integer

Comment: sorry went to fast and amended accordingly

Comment: `())))]))` Wow, those are the most brackets I've seen since Lisp! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Define an `average` function and then use a nested `list`/`dict` comprehension to get the averages for each key for each dictionary in the list.

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> lst = [{'Eva': [4, 8, 2]}, {'Ana': [57, 45, 57]}, {'Ada': [12]}]
>>> avg = lambda x: int(round(sum(x) / len(x)))
>>> [{k: avg(v) for k, v in d.items()} for d in lst]
[{'Eva': 5}, {'Ana': 53}, {'Ada': 12}]
```

If you want the average to be wrapped in a list, just use `[avg(v)]`:

```
>>> [{k: [avg(v)] for k, v in d.items()} for d in lst]
[{'Eva': [5]}, {'Ana': [53]}, {'Ada': [12]}]
```

Comment: The same I was going to post, but OP wants the average in a list

Comment: Yes because I will use that list to turn it into a .csv file

Comment: Actually nevermind the average does not need to be in a list

Comment: All the OP needs to do is wrap `avg(v)` in `[]` to get the list if he wants it.

Comment: Isn't `int(round(sum(x) / len(x)))` redundant? I think `round(sum(x) / len(x))` yields the same result.

Comment: @Tonechas No, `round` will still produce a floating point number, like `5.0` instead of `5`.

Comment: @tobias_k You're right, I figured it out just 1 ms after posting my comment :(

Answer (score 1):

This is an "easy to read and understand" solution. I guess from your question that you do not have too much confidence with python so, I will keep it very basic.

```
myList = [{'Eva': [4, 8, 2]}, {'Ana': [57, 45, 57]}, {'Ada': [12]}]

result = []
for item in myList:
    for k,v in item.items(): #use iteritems() if Python2
        average = round(sum(v)/len(v)) #round to the closest integer
        result.append({k:average})

>>>print(result)
[{'Eva': 5}, {'Ana': 53}, {'Ada': 12}]
```

Comment: I need the output to be a list of dictionaries, so the function needs to return that list

Comment: I have modified accordingly. Now result is a list of dicts

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner:

#### In:

`[{el.keys()[0]: [int( round(1.0 * sum(el.values()[0]) / len(el.values()[0]) ))]} for el in li]`

#### Out:

`[{'Eva': [5]}, {'Ana': [53]}, {'Ada': [12]}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
data = [{'Eva': [4, 8, 2]}, {'Ana': [57, 45, 57]}, {'Ada': [12]}]
outdata = []

for item in data:
    tmp = {}
    for key, val in item.iteritems():
        avg = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, val) / len(val)
        tmp[key] = [avg]
    outdata.append(tmp)
```

Which will also work in the case where you have dictionaries with multiple keys (although the additional variable is probably wasteful if that can never happen).